# Confused by how ActiveX works

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex

I need to use an ActiveX control with a C# ASP.net web application I am creating and I am a little confused as to how this works.  I have the dll that has the ActiveX control referenced in my code but am having a hard time figuring out what to do next. From what I can tell I need to add

```
<object id="testx" classid="Library/activeX.dll"></object>
```

to my html code but I cannot seem to connect to it from my C# behind code.

I know I am over looking something or maybe just way off on my understanding of how these work.  I got my ActiveX Control dll from a third party so I'm not creating the control just trying to use it.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of ActiveX control is it?

Comment: It is used to allow me to connect to a client scanner from a website.  I'm not sure if that is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can add runat="server" in order to access in code behind

```
<object id="testx" classid="" runat="server"></object>
```

regedit : Use the left pane to open the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID directory. This contains keys for all the ActiveX controls installed on your computer

Comment: Thanks. Now it wants a GUID for the classid and I don't know where I find that.

Comment: Use the left pane to open the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID directory. This contains keys for all the ActiveX controls installed on your computer

Comment: I'am happy to herlp you use229133

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but when you embed an ActiveX control in a (ASP.NET-/HTML-) page (using `<object ...>`), then it will run on the client-side, in the browser (IE only). So you have no way to directly access it from your server-side code.

Also, for the ActiveX control to work, it will have to be installed on the client computer. (note: while you are developing, then the client and server will probably be the same computer).

On the other hand, if you want to use the ActiveX control on the server-side, then there is no need to embed it into the HTML code. Instead you create an instance of the ActiveX control in your server-side code (code-behind).

Let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: I thought the point with ActiveX was that if you didn't have what you needed on your client machine then it would ask you to download something?  Is that something I have to setup?